# How do I validate only certain strings in C# MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation

How to validate only certain string in C#? For example if I have 4 colors RED, BLUE, GREEN and BLACK I only wants user to enter these colors. If a user enters other color such as WHITE than, the code throws an error like "
How do I use this in my model validation in MVC C#?

For example:
MODEL:

```
public int ID {get; set;}
public string color {get; set;}
```

CONTROLLER:

```
    [HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(
            [Bind(Include = "ID, color")] tblColor myColor)
        {
            try { 
                if (ModelState.IsValid && ModelState != ModelState)

  if(myColor == RED, GREEN, BLUE, BLACK)
{
                    db.Projects.Add(myColor);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
else
{
// error == "You are only allow to insert one of the RED, BLUE, GREEN, BLACK";
}
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
               // Error message
            }
            return View(myColor);
        }
```

Comment: Please show us what you've tried and how its failed rather than suggesting that we write it for you.

Comment: Simpliest UI would be to just use a dropdownlist, but you can always use a `[RegularExpression]` attribute if you want to annoy your users.

Comment: If you have a limited set of choices they can make, then give them a selection of those choices rather than forcing them to type them in as text and possibly get them wrong.  Use a dropdown, radio buttons, listbox, etc... then only those choices can be selected.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a dropdown box with those values, but that still doesn't validate the response.

For server side validation, and assuming you have the value coming in via a parameter, something like this will work:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Submit(string color)
    {
        string[] validColors = new string[] { "RED", "BLUE", "GREEN", "BLACK" };
        if (!validColors.Contains(color))
        {
            ViewBag.ErrorMessage = color + " is not a valid color.";
            return View();
        }
    }
```